Particle system not taking VertexWeightProximity into account
I have a empty controlling an objects vertexweightproximity: going from blue to red-full range. But when I connect that same vertex group to a particle systems density setting, it doesn't take the VWG modifier into account and just spawns in particles no matter the range? I want the density to update along side the vertex weight proximity modifier so I can animate when theres a spawn of particles with an empty based on the objects effected height.




still spawning


hello could you please share your file?

Looks like a bug, because it works in Hair mode, not in Emitter mode (tested on 4.2.3).

@moonboots  here

Yes I think I tried it before with no success as well

I've reported it as a bug in blender issues, well see what they say.

I do not think it is a bug, Density is a specific term which does not really apply to particles being emitted over time. The number of particles is set and the frame range over which they are emitted. This gives a particle rate per frame. This is not density, and also the other particle settings which can be controlled by vertex groups clearly show by their name that they are intended for hair particles (Length, Clump, Kink etc.). It simply is not possible to change the particle rate per frame with a vertex group.

Say, you have 1000 particles to be emitted over 200 frames, makes 5 particles per frame. If you change the emission rate dynamically with a Density setting which for example is set to 0 on 100 frames, this would mean you either get only 500 particles or on the remaining there have to be emitted 10 particles per frame. This does not work. The Density for these particles only uses one differentiation: if there weight is 0 at the beginning of the particle emission, they will not emit particles. If the weight is > 0, they will emit particles - no matter if the value changes over time.

@Gordon Brinkmann I think you can give that as an answer

@moonboots Yep, thought about that but I was on my phone when I wrote it... I would rather prepare a proper answer later with example screenshots to show how it works.

The Density group selection in the Vertex Groups settings of the particle system is (mostly) for hair particles, like the other group selections as well as the names might already suggest: Length, Clump, Kink etc..
The particle system set to Emitter is given a certain particle per frame emission rate when you set a Number for the particles together with the range in which they should be emitted by the Frame Start and End values.
Let's say you have a Number of 1000 set to emit from frame 1 until frame 100. This means, Blender will emit 1000 particles in 100 frames i.e. 10 per frame (more or less 10 per frame, depending on random seed etc.).
This number will be used for the complete simulation and no matter which density you have set somewhere, in the end there will be 1000 particles emitted - because this is an initial setting of the particle simulation which cannot be changed dynamically. Values like Number, Frame Start/End cannot be animated either to change over time.
So, what does that mean? In the following scenarios I use an icosphere to be instanced on particles to show the object count (because particle halos do not count as objects), also a high lifetime so that all particles are still alive at the end. No matter what density I use, the object count at the end will always be the 1001, the emitter + 1000 particles.
Simple setup: the whole emitter plane has a weight of 1 or 100%, so particles emit everywhere.

After frame 100 when all particles are emitted, there are 1001 objects: the emitter and the particles:

Now I reduce the weight to 0 on most parts of the plane, and leave only a small part in the center at a weight of 1. But this is no longer 100% of the plane - and just to be clear, I still have all vertices inside the group, just most of them with a weight of 0. So 1394 of 1649 vertices have a weight of 0, which means only 15.5% of the plane are set to emit particles.

But does that mean, I get only 155 particles at the end? No, the 1000 will all be emitted in the center:

The Density group selection does take weight differences into account though. In the following example there are two areas with a weight > 0. One where the vertices have a weight of 1, in the other they have a weight of 0.05:

And just like before, at the end it all sums up to 1000 particles, only that the red area now emitted a little less than 1000, the ones which were emitted in the low density area:

It is not even necessary that there is any vertex with a weight of 1, here the left area is 0.05 like before while on the right it is just a weight of 0.2:

But still it results in 1000 particles:

This just does not work dynamically. At the beginning of the simulation will be determined how many of the particles will be emitted in which area. So in the example above, there is an area with a weight of 0.05 and one with 0.2, together they have to emit 100% of the particles.
0.05 + 0.2 = 0.25, and 0.05 is 20% of 0.25 and 0.2 is 80%, so the left area emits 200 particles and the right one 800 particles. Changes over time would have to be recalculated and can result in problems, like for example the emitter has just emitted 500 particles but now the density is suddenly 0 - how should the remaining 500 be emitted? I do not say this is not possible, but it is not how the old particle system in Blender works.
Anyway, this will result in what you might deem to be a bug: the weight distribution changes, but the emission remains the same throughout the simulation:

By the way, I did the last part with Weight Paint. Basically one might think that with baking the weight paint cache and baking the particles, this could help with the dynamics, but not really: the particle emission will use the weight distribution from the frame on which you bake for the whole simulation.
In the previous animation, I was on frame 1 when I hit the Bake All Dynamics button. In the following animation I started baking on frame 70 when the vertex weight has already moved closer to the left border, but every setting is the same like before:

A side note: if you do not get anything of this to work, make sure you have placed the Dynamic Paint before the ParticleSystem in the modifier stack and the option Use Modifier Stack is enabled under Source in the particle settings:

Also if the particle distribution sometimes does not update to follow the vertex weight, it helps if you quickly switch the emitter to Edit Mode and back to Object Mode.
Sorry, this was a very long explanation why this is not exactly a bug, just the way the particle emitter works unfortunately.

Thank you for the explenation. A dev told me it's probably not going to be fixed since geometry nodes is now a thing. Sucks but whatever

@FruitJuice Well, whatever he told you, I never saw this as a bug anyway. You also cannot change a cloth mesh in the midst of a simulation either or change the resolution of a smoke domain. Some simulations work like that, they have parameters that cannot be changed mid-sim.
